# Picture quality when posting pictures on social media

Tags: canon, photo-editing, image-quality, social-media

I've been taking pictures of my self or my family with my camera for quite a while now, and i normally use those pics on social media, but the thing is... the pics are so heavy that it takes too long to upload one or the site doesn't support the size of the picture because it's too big, and its way to lower it down ends up being by lowering the quality. So i've tried to resize them but when i do they lose quality almost completely to the point where i post one and it just looks awful and kinda blurry and it looks like taken from a phone with a very average camera instead of a nicer camera work unlike to how the original picture looks which is very good quality. I honestly don't know what to do anymore, i want to post my pictures with the same quality i see when i see them in my computer and directly on the camera. Please help me!!! Also my camera is a canon eos 1200D and for resizing ive used Photoshop cs6

Comment: What tool in Photoshop are you using to resize, and what settings are you using in that tool? Note that few social media sites allow full-size-from-camera images, so you're never going to get *exactly* that, but you should be able to get relatively decent results.

Comment: Sorry to be annoying, but please use paragraphs and proper punctuation. Your question is very difficult to read.

Comment: What is "social media"? I have uploaded pictures from my camera to Facebook and it has no problems with the size. Sure the quality is compromised by Facebook compressing the image but it's not slow or impossible as you say.

Answer (score 1):

> i want to post my pictures with the same quality i see when i see them in my computer and directly on the camera.

What you want generally isn't possible. Social media sites typically resize and recompress images with their own preferred settings. You cannot force them to do otherwise.

If you must have images stored at the highest quality, you can purchase a Google Pixel phone, which will let you store original quality images on Google Photos. Or you may purchase storage space from a file or image hosting site.

Answer (score 0):

"Resize" can mean several things - physical dimensions (theoretical with digital pictures, but they'll still have values for width x height), or the size of the file in pixels or in bytes.

If the problem is that the sites aren't accepting the physical dimensions, you should be able to change these dimensions in your editing software while increasing the image resolution (pixels per inch) - if your software makes this a two stage process, increase the resolution first. This will give you a file with smaller physical dimensions, but reasonable resolution and a similar pixel count or file size to the original. It won't be the same quality, but it could be close.

I would recommend changing these parameters in your editing software - the website should give guidance on the dimensions and resolution it will accept, and letting the website make its own adjustment is unlikely to give as good a result.

If the problem is that the website is limiting the pixel count or file size, there is little you can do - the images stored on the site will be at a lower resolution compared to the original.

If it seems the file is taking too long to upload, that's because it's a large file containing a lot of information. The only way to achieve shorter upload times on the same connection will be to reduce the information transmitted by reducing the file size or using a file format that compresses the data, both of which will give a lower quality picture.